# Scanner Cannot be resolved to a type 9

Tags: compiler-errors

I am trying to write a program to allow the user to input up to two polynomials and I keep getting the "Scanner cannot be resolved to a type" error and I am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Polynomial2
{
   public static double evaluate( double x, double[] coefs)
  {
    int i, coef, deg;
    double total=0, poly;
   Scanner sc= new scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter degree");
    deg=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter x");
    x=sc.nextInt();
    if(coefs !=null)
    {
      for (i=0; i<= deg; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("Enter coefficent for" +i);
        coef=sc.nextInt();
        total= total+coef*Math.pow(x,i);
      }
    } 
    return type (total);
    System.out.println("Total="+total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner sc= new scanner(System.in);
```

Notice how "Scanner" is capitalized. You need to capitalize Scanner to the right of the new.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Is there any advice you could give me to write this program, Is my structure correct or is there a better way to allow the user to input two polynomials?

Comment: Usually you name your Scanner keyboard. It is common practice. It is isn't wrong not to but you normal just name it keyboard. Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);You could use a do while loop to filter out bad output. For example, if you only want integers above 0 you could have the loop keep running if x<= 0 and stop if x > 0. Also if you are going to be rerunning this program any times you could try using static methods. Although I wouldn't worry too much about Static Methods as you are beginning and you will hitting later in your CS courses Let me know if you need any more help, AlphaCoder

Comment: Can you show me what the do while loop should look like?

Comment: // We are using a Do While Loop to get a number greater than 0
// The loop will continue repeating untill the integer i is greater than 0
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lumberjacks {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = 0;
  do {
   System.out.println("Give a number greater than 0 please");
   i = keyboard.nextInt();
   if(i <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Number must be greater than 0");
   }
  }while (i <= 0);
   System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");}}

Comment: Had to make it not spaced out properly due to the limited number of characters.                                                                                                        If you need any help let me know, AlphaCoder